# conditions OR in join cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am a novice in cake and I'm having trouble with a query I want to do in a tables.

```
        $options['joins'] = array(
        array('table'=>'users_views',
                  'alias' => 'UserView',
                  'type' => 'inner',
                  'conditions' => array(
                    'View.id = UserView.view_id',
                    'UserView.user_id' => $user_id,
                    'UserView.like' => 1
                   ),   
            )
        );
        $options['order'] = array('View.created' => 'desc');
        $options['limit'] = 10;
```

That's my query so far, but what I need now add an OR condition. In this condition OR need to add

```
'UserView.user_id' => $user_id,
'UserView.like' => 0
```

I need the query returns the data that matches or are mine and the LIKE value is 0 if it is very difficult to understand please tell me.
Any help or advice will be well received.

Comment: Please add the actual SQL you are trying to generate in your question. It will make the required Cakephp code easier to show you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build the `conditions` like -

```
'conditions' => array(
     0 => array('View.id = UserView.view_id'),
     1 => array('UserView.user_id' => $user_id),
     3 => 'UserView.like => 1 OR UserView.like => 0'
),
```

Or with using `OR` -

```
'conditions' => array(
     0 => array('View.id = UserView.view_id'),
     1 => array('UserView.user_id' => $user_id),
     2 => 'UserView.like IN (0, 1)'
),
```

Comment: This returns me all the records. What I need is that returns ALL LIKE MINE having 1 OR LIKE 0.

Comment: Sorry I'm trying to make it work, shoot me an error Error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW, expecting ')'

Comment: My mistake. they have to be in array. Updated.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, still does not work, but keep trying!

Comment: Hey, upgrade my core and everything worked well for me. A consultation, as I can be returned in the query, the value of UserView.like?

Comment: Your 1st example is invalid. Basic PHP violation: Cannot use a key twice in an array: `'UserView.like'`. Just use 'field IN' => ...

Comment: Thanx @mark . First it was two different keys. Forgot change them after edit.

Answer (score 2):

The following should work:

```
$options['joins'] = array(
            array('table'=>'users_views',
                'alias' => 'UserView',
                'type' => 'inner',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'View.id = UserView.view_id',
                    'OR' => array(
                        'UserView.user_id' => $user_id,
                        'UserView.like' => 1
                    )
                ),
            )
        );
        $options['order'] = array('View.created' => 'desc');
        $options['limit'] = 10;
```